# Conflict of OllyDbg plugins

Tags: ollydbg, anti-debugging, plugin

I have recently started using plugins for OllyDbg 1.10. Thanks to this [site](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.9), I have an idea of the capabilities of the plugins for OllyDbg.

As I have only a very basic idea of how plugins work, I was wondering, do plugins interfere with each other? For example, if I use multiple plugins that deals with the same anti-debugging techniques, is it possible that they may conflict with each other and mess with what I would ideally want, which is to hide my debugger? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible for Ollydbg's plugin to interfere with each other. Generally you should only keep plugins that you use.

The best anti-debugging plugins for Ollydbg as of now are *[ScyllaHide](https://bitbucket.org/NtQuery/scyllahide)* for user-mode and *[TitanHide](https://bitbucket.org/mrexodia/titanhide)* for kernel mode. Both of them are open source and well maintained.